# PHP, Apache, FreeBSD permissions issue

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

Persumably, this is a *nix permissions question. I'm a Java dev trying to write some simple PHP code. We have a production machine running FreeBSD+Apache.

I'm trying to create a directory called 'ccc' as in '/var/www/aaa/bbb/ccc'

Directories 'aaa' and 'bbb' already exist.

This is ls -ltrh output for directory 'aaa':

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root     root      12K Jun 10 05:27 aaa
```

This is ls -ltrh output for directory 'bbb':

```
drwxr-xr-x 3557      858      856 116K May 28 06:15 bbb
```

This PHP code does not create the directory '/var/www/aaa/bbb/ccc'. Says 'mkdir FAILED'.

```
<?php

$path = "/var/www/aaa/bbb/ccc";
if(!file_exists($path)) {
        echo "Path does not exist, creating [".$path."]...";

        if(mkdir($path, 0777, true)) {
                echo "mkdir PASSED...";
        }
        else {
                echo "mkdir FAILED...";
        }
}
else {
        echo "Path does exist[".$path."]...";
}

?>
```

This is ls -ltrh output for the php code:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      366 Jun 10 07:14 mdtest.php
```

How can I create the directory 'ccc'? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Under which user are you running the script?

Comment: Running script from browser. ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)' gives apache    4659  0.0  2.2 372284 13836 ?        S    Jun08   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd. Not sure if that answers your question

Comment: Also ran phpinfo() and the browser reports User/Group : apache(48)/48

Comment: The user and group for the directory `bbb` are not in the passwd and group databeses. That's why you see a numeric UID and GID. This can indicate disk corruption. And try `chown root:wheel bbb`.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that your apache web server has not write permission to */var/www/aaa/bbb*. I dont know BSD, in debian is Apache running under *www-data* user. So you have to change owner of */var/www/aaa/bbb* to apache user.

Run `chown -hR apache /var/www`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Will test on production machine when it is made available and get back. Any other inputs in the meanwhile would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, you were right. However, since this is a production machine, we don't have the "permission to change any permissions"! We are in the process of moving all files to AWS/S3. Thx again

Answer (score 1):

You may set all to write permission: `chmod a+rw /var/www/aaa/bbb`

Comment: Thanks for your input and I'm sure it would work, but this is a production machine and off limits to such changes

Comment: Another user must have execute permission to access /var/www/aaa/.

In my practice I set a+rw permission, look on created file and change owner (`chown`) /var/www/aaa/bbb on this uid and set write permission for this user only. Change group owner (`chgrp`) and group permission (`chmod 575   /var/www/aaa/bbb`) must be work too.